# Objective-C: floorf( ) returns wrong value

Tags: objective-c, math, floor

Here is the code:

```
    float passedPrice = 2.953;
    float placed = 1000.0; //3 decimals
    NSLog("%f", placed); // Gives 2953;
    float withNoFractions = floorf(passedPrice * placed);
```

The value stored in withNoFractions is 2952! It shall be 2953. What is really strange is that it works some time.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffloating-point-gui.de%2F&ei=tqq_UcPJKsav0AHymoDgCg&usg=AFQjCNEZ7cdKN5bOhpWTIQQCev6G53AQYg&sig2=Ou9Gjbv655Pv6sQErqscMw&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmQ)

Comment: I took a look at the article. Still, this doesn't solve the problem. passedPrice * placed = 2953 not 2952. Why flooring it give 2952?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many decimal floating point fractions cannot be represented as exact fractions in binary, so they have to be approximated.  2.953 is being approximated as something like 2.95299999. When you multiply by 1000, the result is 2952.99999, and when you get the floor of this, it's 2952.

To solve this, you can either use `round()` instead of `ffloorf()`, or you can add 0.5 before calling `ffloorf()`:

```
float withNoFractions = floorf(passedPrice * placed + 0.5);
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was using "po" in Xcode instead of NSLog() which gives your answer. How to solve that though?

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I am facing a related issue with this algorithm and opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159611/objective-c-flooring-to-3-decimals-correctly

Comment: That seems like essentially the same problem. You use this solution, then divide by 1000.